# Python replace string pattern with output of function

Tags: python, regex

I have a string in Python, say `The quick @red fox jumps over the @lame brown dog.`

I'm trying to replace each of the words that begin with `@` with the output of a function that takes the word as an argument.

```
def my_replace(match):
    return match + str(match.index('e'))

#Psuedo-code

string = "The quick @red fox jumps over the @lame brown dog."
string.replace('@%match', my_replace(match))

# Result
"The quick @red2 fox jumps over the @lame4 brown dog."
```

Is there a clever way to do this?

Comment: what you have is good. you do it in one statement.

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10454359/14055985

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You can pass a function to [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub). The function will receive a match object as the argument, use `.group()` to extract the match as a string.

```
>>> def my_replace(match):
...     match = match.group()
...     return match + str(match.index('e'))
...
>>> string = "The quick @red fox jumps over the @lame brown dog."
>>> re.sub(r'@\w+', my_replace, string)
'The quick @red2 fox jumps over the @lame4 brown dog.'
```

Answer (score 12):

I wasn't aware you could pass a function to a `re.sub()` either. Riffing on @Janne Karila's answer to solve a problem I had, the approach works for multiple capture groups, too.

```
import re

def my_replace(match):
    match1 = match.group(1)
    match2 = match.group(2)
    match2 = match2.replace('@', '')
    return u"{0:0.{1}f}".format(float(match1), int(match2))

string = 'The first number is 14.2@1, and the second number is 50.6@4.'
result = re.sub(r'([0-9]+.[0-9]+)(@[0-9]+)', my_replace, string)

print(result)
```

Output:

`The first number is 14.2, and the second number is 50.6000.`

This simple example requires all capture groups be present (no optional groups).

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
import re

match = re.compile(r"@\w+")
items = re.findall(match, string)
for item in items:
    string = string.replace(item, my_replace(item)
```

This will allow you to replace anything that starts with @ with whatever the output of your function is. 
I wasn't very clear if you need help with the function as well. Let me know if that's the case

Comment: `re.findall(pattern, string)` -- please fix

Comment: This is actually pretty useful as it allows you to replace only the matched elements in the string.

Answer (score 2):

A short one with regex and reduce:

```
>>> import re
>>> pat = r'@\w+'
>>> reduce(lambda s, m: s.replace(m, m + str(m.index('e'))), re.findall(pat, string), string)
'The quick @red2 fox jumps over the @lame4 brown dog.'
```