# Python pandas: use of DataFrame.replace function with a function as a value

Tags: python, pandas

Using Python pandas, I have been attempting to use a function, as one of a few replacement values for a `pandas.DataFrame` (i.e. one of the replacements should itself be the result of a function call). My understanding is that [`pandas.DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) delegates internally to `re.sub` and that anything that works with it should also work with `pandas.DataFrame.replace`, provided that the `regex` parameter is set to `True`.

Accordingly, I followed the guidance provided [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12597709) on stack**overflow**, but pertaining to `re.sub`, and attempted to apply it to `pandas.DataFrame.replace` (using replace with `regex=True, inplace=True` and with **`to_replace`** set as either a nested dictionary, if specifying a specific column, or otherwise as two lists, per its [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)). My code works fine without using a function call, but fails if I try to provide a function as one of the replacement values, despite doing so in the same manner as `re.sub` (which was tested, and worked correctly). I realize that the function is expected to accept a match object as its only required parameter and return a string.

Instead of the resultant `DataFrame` having the *result* of the function call, it contains the *function itself* (i.e. as a first-class, unparameterized, object).

Why is this occurring and how can I get this to work correctly (return and store the function's result)? If this is not possible, I would appreciate if a viable and "Pandasonic" alternative could be suggested.

---

I provide an example of this below:

```
def fn(match):
    id = match.group(1)
    result = None
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
        if 'string' in line:
            result = line.split()[-1]
    return (result or id)

data.replace(to_replace={'col1': {'string': fn}},
             regex=True, inplace=True)
```

The above does not work, in that it replaces the right search string, but replaces it with:

```
<function fn at 0x3ad4398>
```

For the above (contrived) example, the expected output would be that all values of "string" in `col1` are substituted for the string returned from `fn`.

However, `import re; print(re.sub('string', fn, 'test string'))`, works as expected (and as [previously depicted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12597709)).

Comment: just wanted to note, it seems like you are not using to_replace correctly, from the docs "If this is True then to_replace must be a string.", however your to_replace is a dict

Comment: @dermen I think you might be correct that the real issue here is what you pointed out, regarding **```to_replace```** being a string when using ```regex=True```. I guess I expected that it wasn't referring to the values of the **```to_replace```** clause, but that was likely misguided...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My current solution (which seems sub-optimal and *ad hoc* to me) is as follows (ellipses indicate irrelevant additional code, which has been omitted; specific data used are contrived):

```
def _fn(match):
    ...
    return ...


def _multiple_replace(text, repl_dictionary):
    """Adapted from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15175239
       Returns the result for the first regex that matches
       the provided text."""
    for pattern in repl_dictionary.keys():
        regex = re.compile(pattern)
        res, num_subs = regex.subn(repl_dictionary[pattern], text)
        if num_subs > 0:
            break

    return res


repl_dict = {'ABC.*(\w\w\w)': _fn, 'XYZ': 'replacement_string'}
data['col1'] = data['col1'].apply(_multiple_replace,
                                  repl_dictionary=repl_dict)
```