# regex: remove 's' from the end of every word except starting from capital letter but not at the beginning?

Tags: python, regex

Condition is:
's' is removed at the end of every word if
it is not in the middle of the sentence.

The input string is:

```
Ses Holmes os. Sos
```

The output should be:

```
Se Holmes o. So
```

I started with this condition

```
([A-Z][a-z]+)
```

but got stuck on it. It cannot be inserted into negative lookbehind.

Comment: You don't really need regex here (although it *can* be achieved using it).

Comment: Can you explain why Holmes ends in an 's' in your example?

Comment: I think he wants to remove a terminal `s` from all words except uppercase words (names?) that occur after the first word in a sentence. Which leads to the questions "What if the first word in a sentence *is* a name?" and "How can you tell where a sentence begins?" (looking for punctuation is not going to work, Dr. Watson...)

Comment: This is impossible without a very clear definition of a) a word and b) the start and end of a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression already looks good, although it doesn’t catch words like `café`.

To do the replacemnt, you should call `re.sub` with a function, as explained in [Python replace string pattern with output of function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597370/python-replace-string-pattern-with-output-of-function). In that function you can implement the exceptions to the rule, so that you express them as Python code, not as regular expression.

Comment: That won't work - the exceptions are based on the context of the match, and that's not present when you've passed the match to the function.