# Bulk Search and Replace issue links in git commit messages while ignoring branch names

Tags: string, git, powershell, replace, jira

I am doing a bulk search and replace for thousands of commit messages in a git repository. Essentially my goal is to restore Jira issue linkage for the repository to a new Jira project key.

```
Old project key: TEST
New project key: TESTPSW
```

The following text that I want replaced can be anywhere in the commit message. Assume that 'X' refers to an arbitrary digit (0-9)

Replacements:

```
TEST-X -> TESTPSW-X
TEST-XX -> TESTPSW-XX
TEST-XXX -> TESTPSW-XXX
TEST-XXXX -> TESTPSW-XXXX
TEST-XXXXX -> TESTPSW-XXXXX
TEST_X -> TESTPSW-X
TEST_XX -> TESTPSW-XX
TEST_XXX -> TESTPSW-XXX
TEST_XXXX -> TESTPSW-XXXX
TEST_XXXXX -> TESTPSW-XXXXX
TEST=X -> TESTPSW-X
TEST=XX -> TESTPSW-XX
TEST=XXX -> TESTPSW-XXX
TEST=XXXX -> TESTPSW-XXXX
TEST=XXXXX -> TESTPSW-XXXXX
```

I need to ignore the use of 'TEST-' when it is included in a branch name. There are thousands of commits with different syntax of where/how this appears, here are some examples:

```
Finish merge branch 'master' into TEST-3316-support-configurable-.....
Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/master' into TEST-3390-refactor-.....
Merge pull request #497 in TEST_SW/test from TEST-3316-support-configurable-....
Merge pull request #549 in TEST_SW/test from bugfix/TEST-3419-mfa-s-....
Merge branch 'master' of ssh://*******.***.******.com:7999/test_sw/test into feature/TEST-973-hw-monitor-....
Merge branch 'feature/TEST-3421/refactor-sensor-code' of ssh://*******.***.******.com:7999/test_sw/test into feature/TEST-973-hw-monitor-....
Merge pull request #559 in TEST_SW/test from TEST-3436-add-additional-utilities-.....
```

Also ignores TEST-SCD usage:

```
TEST-SCDX
TEST-SCDXX
TEST-SCDXXX
TEST-SCDXXXX
TEST-SCDXXXXX
```

The following powershell commands are what I have used to this point. This successfully performs the search and replace for TEST-X -> TESTPSW-X (along with XX, XXX, XXXX, and XXXXX). But this does not accomplish the other replacements, and does not ignore the examples written above that I would like for my search and replace to ignore.

```
PS C:\_\test> git filter-repo --commit-callback '
>> msg = commit.message.decode(\"utf-8\")
>> newmsg = msg.replace(\"TEST-\", \"TESTPSW-\")
>> commit.message = newmsg.encode(\"utf-8\")
>> ' --force
```

I believe I could possibly use some sort of regex to accomplish all the replacements I've listed above, while also satisfying all of the ignores. I would appreciate any help as to how I would write a regex to do this, or advice on if it is even possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Why does this have a `powershell` tag?

Answer (score 0):

See: https://pythonexamples.org/python-re-sub/

Please try this regex, `(?<!TEST-SCD)(?<!branch \'\w+/)` indicates the match doesn't have "TEST-SCD" or "branch 'any_word/" before it. `lambda m: m.group(0).replace(\"TEST\", \"TESTPSW\")` replaces "TEST" with "TESTPSW". Ref: [Python lambda with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454359/python-lambda-with-regex)

```
git filter-repo --commit-callback '
>> import re
>> msg = commit.message.decode(\"utf-8\")
>> newmsg = re.sub(r\"(?<!TEST-SCD)(?<!branch .+/)(TEST[-_=]\d{1,5})\", lambda m: m.group(0).replace(\"TEST\", \"TESTPSW\"), msg)
>> commit.message = newmsg.encode(\"utf-8\")
>> ' --force
```

Test and let me know if this works for you.